# implementing custom authentication with devise, 'mapping' member

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm trying to write a custom (remote) authentication for devise. 
All the API doc I've found is [this example](http://4trabes.com/2012/10/31/remote-authentication-with-devise/), so I'm proceding by trials and errors.

I'm particularly interested in understanding what does the 'mapping.to.new' line do.

It seems to be crucial since if it returns nil, the authentication process will fail.

But what are those "mappings", where are they defined?

Furthermore, the call

```
 mapping.to.new
```

has something strange, it seems like an object instantiation... isn't it?

I've also found a different implementation, that looks like:

```
resource = mapping.to.where(["username = ?", auth_params[:username]]).first
```

where it seems that mapping.to returns a relation object, but again, where am i expected to define what my mappings are?

```
  class RemoteAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
    def authenticate!
      auth_params = authentication_hash
      auth_params[:password] = password

      resource = mapping.to.new

      return fail! unless resource

      if validate(resource){ resource.remote_authentication(auth_params) }
        success!(resource)
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

`mapping.to` is instance to class of model on which you map authentification ( often is a `User` or `Admin`). 
So if you call `mapping.to.new` is the same as you call `User.new`. 
And if you call `mapping.to.where(...)` it return same result as `User.where(...)`.

More you can find on [mapping.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/mapping.rb)